# could found maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, xstream, karaf

```
karaf@root> install -s mvn:com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.7
Bundle ID: 169
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to start bundle mvn:com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.7: 
    Unresolved constraint in bundle xstream [169]: 
    Unable to resolve 169.0: missing requirement [169.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=sun.misc)
```

i can not find the proper maven dependency for xstream ... I searched too many links but the result is same ... is there any alternative way to overcome this issue ... can i make maven bundle form JAR? if yes then how ?

Comment: This seems like an OSGi error for me. Do you have any mirror set in your `settings.xml` for maven? The requested library seems to be there in the central repo: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.thoughtworks.xstream|xstream|1.4.7|jar

Comment: i solved this problem through adding this missing class "sun.misc" in the config.properties file of karaf... As i got that "sun.misc" is the library of jdk that is why karaf could'nt use it so i add this class in config.properties file of karaf and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved this problem through adding this missing class "sun.misc" in the config.properties file of karaf... As i got that "sun.misc" is the library of jdk that is why karaf could'nt use it so i add this class in config.properties file of karaf and the problem resolved.